# Filtering objects in Django based on a related field, excluding certain values

Tags: django, django-models

I have Consumers, who receive ConsumerEmails.

```
class Consumer(Model):
    pass

class ConsumerEmail(Model):
    summary = models.TextField()
    consumer = models.ForeignKey(Consumer, related_name="emails")
```

I want the list of Consumers who have received no emails, or no emails except the one that asks them to verify their email address. That is, if I left-joined the tables in this example I would want ids 1, 2, 3 but not 4, 5.

```
╔════╤══════════════════════════════╤════════╗
║ id │ email.summary                │ select ║
╠════╪══════════════════════════════╪════════╣
║ 1  │ NULL                         │ Yes    ║
╟────┼──────────────────────────────┼────────╢
║ 2  │ Sent email verification code │ Yes    ║
╟────┼──────────────────────────────┼────────╢
║ 3  │ Sent email verification code │ Yes    ║
╟────┼──────────────────────────────┼────────╢
║ 3  │ Sent email verification code │        ║
╟────┼──────────────────────────────┼────────╢
║ 4  │ Sent email verification code │ No     ║
╟────┼──────────────────────────────┼────────╢
║ 4  │ Update on your application   │        ║
╟────┼──────────────────────────────┼────────╢
║ 5  │ Update on your application   │ No     ║
╚════╧══════════════════════════════╧════════╝
```

My attempt was:

```
Consumer.objects.exclude(~Q(emails__summary="Sent email verification code"))
```

but this generates the query

```
SELECT   "api_consumer"."id"
FROM     "api_consumer"
WHERE    NOT (
                  NOT (
                           "api_consumer"."id" IN
                           (
                                  SELECT u1."consumer_id" AS col1
                                  FROM   "api_consumeremail" U1
                                  WHERE  u1."summary" = 'sent email verification code')))
```

which isn't right.  What's the right ORM query?

Comment: You lookup is not that complex for Q objects, did you tried `Consumer.objects.exclude(emails__summary="Sent email verification code")`

Comment: Kapil, that returns all users who have not received the verification code email, including those who have received other emails. I want users who have received no emails, or no emails except the verification code email.

Comment: Can you try `Consumer.objects.filter( Q(emails__isnull=True) | ~Q(emails__summary="Sent email verification code") )`..... You also said _those who have received other emails_, exclude them too(not much clear to me ).

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the question with an example to make it clearer. That query returns users who have received emails other than the verification code email. It generates this where clause: WHERE ("api_consumeremail"."id" IS NULL OR NOT ("api_consumer"."id" IN (SELECT U1."consumer_id" AS Col1 FROM "api_consumeremail" U1 WHERE (U1."summary" = Sent email verification code AND U1."id" = ("api_consumeremail"."id")))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
consumers_with_emails = ConsumerEmail.objects.exclude(
    summary="Sent email verification code"
).values_list('consumer_id', flat=True).distinct()

Consumer.objects.exclude(
    id__in=consumers_with_emails
)
```

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't work, it shows users who received the verification email and other emails. The query translates to     SELECT          "api_consumer"."id"
    FROM            "api_consumer"
    LEFT OUTER JOIN "api_consumeremail" 
    ON              ( 
                                    "api_consumer"."id" = "api_consumeremail"."consumer_id") 
    WHERE           ( 
                                    "api_consumeremail"."id" IS NULL 
                    OR              "api_consumeremail"."summary" = 'sent email verification code')

Comment: @Matthew Edited. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I took out the .annotate.filter part which was causing an exception, and now it works